# Login page : not able to compare string values

Tags: asp.net, string, textbox, compare

Source Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANIRUDH;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USER_LOGIN WHERE USERID='" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND PASSWORD='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string userid = txtUserName.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    dr.Read();

    if((dr["USERID"].ToString() == userid) && (dr["PASSWORD"].ToString() == password))
    {
        Response.Redirect("/WebForm1.aspx", true);
    }
    else
    { 
        Response.Write("Invalid");
    }

}
```

Problem:

This always giving ... when am entering correct username and password as it is in database...
when I used LABELs to show the values come from database ... they r correct and showing ... but while comparing always showing INVALID

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**!

Comment: You aren't actually adding any security here; anyone can still go to `WebForm1.aspx` manually.

Comment: In short, security is _hard_.  Do not re-invent the wheel.  Instead, you should use ASP.Net's built-in membership system, which is actually secure.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the usual SQL injection etc that people are making in the comments, you're actually testing twice. Rather than berate what you're doing, I'll attempt to help "WHY" it's not working.

First off you're selecting a row where the user and password equal inputs and then you're testing the contents of the datareader.

Rather than that, just check if your datareader actually contains anything. If it doesn't then nothing was selected based on your select and therefore the user and password are incorrect.

A simple `dr.HasRows` will let you know if the reader contains anything.

Granted, this may not cure WHY SQL isn't selecting anything.

One thing that might be catching you out is case sensitivity. with your `(dr["USERID"].ToString() == userid` case sensitivity will be important as a string "a" is NOT equal to a string "A".

**UPDATE**

To demonstrate what I mean with regards to HasRows, try this instead - you don't need all the additional `if` statements afterwards. If SQL didn't find a row with the `where` clause, then it's obvious the row doesn't exist with the user and password combo.

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USER_LOGIN WHERE USERID='" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND PASSWORD='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows){
          Response.Redirect("/WebForm1.aspx", true);
    }else{
          Response.Write("Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: both there r lower cases ... if am using only 1 to compare ... like userid or password at a time .. thn its all goin fine ...

Comment: Don't bother with all the `if` statement after getting the data. just check that dr has rows. Adding an edit to show what i mean.